# Objective-C basic authentication issue - http 500 error

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I'm trying to implement Basic authentication in objective C using the code below but I keep getting an http status 500 as my response. Does this POST request look like it's set up correctly? If so - why the status 500 error? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
NSString *oauthUserID = @"APP_ID";
NSString *oauthUserPW = @"APP_PASSWORD";
NSString *brmOauthUrl;
brmOauthUrl = @"http://AUTHENTICATION_URL";

// initialize post
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",oauthUserID,oauthUserPW];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postValue = [postData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:1];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

// set up request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:brmOauthUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",postValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// make connection.
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful = %@",connection);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made = %@",connection);
}
[connection start];
```

Here is what the NSLog(@"Connection Successful = %@",connection); line prints out:

```
`{ URL: http://AUTHENTICATION_URL/oauth/token } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Thu, 05 Mar 2015 13:39:56 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "connect.sid=COOKIE_SID; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }`
```

Comment: If I would get some 500 response code then i would investigate the root cause on that very server that returns the 500.

Comment: BTW, I don't see anything wrong with setting the authentication header field. Would have done it quite similar.